# create slider to change android volume?

Tags: android, slider

Can someone give me an sample code for changing volume through a slider?
I searched and a lot of tutorials requied me to create a whole new class. Is there an easier way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add this to your OnCreate, you have to put your seekbar into the layout xml file:

```
    audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    int curVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    SeekBar volControl = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.volbar);
    volControl.setMax(maxVolume);
    volControl.setProgress(curVolume);
    volControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, arg1, 0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: How do I do this if my audio starts elsewhere (i.e. in a service)? I'm getting a NullPointerException in onProgressChanged when I try to move the bar.

Comment: You should probably put this into a separate question.  You are probably going to have to call into your service to adjust the volume.

Comment: Actually it works fine if your audio starts in a service, it was my stupid mistake.

Comment: Great.. Works like charm.

Answer (score 1):

Travis at the New Boston has a great Video Tutorial on this here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8sr2Y6Aff6Y

Source code for the tutorials can be found here: http://www.mybringback.com/bringers/android/thenewboston-android-series/828/thenewboston-sample-projects/

Answer (score 0):

Six years later, this slightly altered version works for me in Android Studio 3.1. The IDE said I had to declare AudioManager final:

```
        /* volume slider*/
final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
int curVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
SeekBar volControl = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.volControl);
volControl.setMax(maxVolume);
volControl.setProgress(curVolume);
volControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, arg1, 0);
    }
});

//end Volume slider
```